# Radio group in devexpress grid control

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I need to use a radio group (rdoChargeOn) in a devExpress grid control (grdDisb). 
I am getting the rows from stored procedure. 
The problem that I have always the selected index of the radio group = -1 with value = 0. 
Also if I create a new row the value is 0 with no selected item after click enter.

What is the equivalent of rdochargeOn.SelectedIndex in this case? can you help me please?
Kindly Find attached a print screen of the grid.

```
    Private _DisbList As BindingList(Of PropertyDisbursementList)
 _DisbList = New BindingList(Of PropertyDisbursementList)(obj.DisbList)
 GrdDisb.DataSource = _DisbList
 GrdDisb.RefreshDataSource()

rivate Sub BindDisbGrid()
        If RecordId <> -1 Then '' Import the list of disbursement 
            _DisbList = New BindingList(Of PropertyDisbursementList)(obj.DisbList)
        End If
        _DisbList.AllowNew = True
        GrdDisb.DataSource = _DisbList
        GrdDisb.RefreshDataSource()
    End Sub
    Public Sub SaveDisbList()
        Try
            Dim disb As New PropertyDisbursementList
            Dim indx As Int32 = 0
            Dim CategName As String = ""
            Dim objWCF As WCFReference.PropertiesServiceProvider = GetServiceProvider()
            For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.DataRowCount - 1
                If GridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "CategId").ToString <> 0 Then
                    disb = _DisbList(i)
                    If RecordId <> -1 Then
                        disb.PropertyId = RecordId
                        disb.CategName = objWCF.Service.GetCatPropertyDisbursement(disb.CategId)
                        disb.RecordInfo = GetRecordInfo()
                        disb.PropertyId = objWCF.Service.SavePropertyDisbursementList(disb)
                    Else
                        disb.PropertyId = ProId
                        disb.CategName = objWCF.Service.GetCatPropertyDisbursement(disb.CategId)
                        disb.RecordInfo = GetRecordInfo()
                        disb.PropertyId = objWCF.Service.SavePropertyDisbursementList(disb)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            iMessage.ShowError(Nothing, ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

thx in advance,
Regards,
Hadil

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go through this DevExpress thread - [Radio Group as Repository Item not working for multiple rows](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q416581)

As I can suspect about this issue may be that you have not added items to the RadioGroup controls that match the value of current cell of the grid.

check this example -

```
List<int> uncheckedID = new List<int>();

public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    gridControl1.DataSource = CreateTable(10);

}     
private static DataTable CreateTable(int RowCount)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    tbl.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    tbl.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    tbl.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(int));
    tbl.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
    for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
        tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { String.Format("Name{0}", i), i, i % 3, DateTime.Now.AddHours(i) });
    return tbl;
}  
private void gridView1_CustomDrawRowFooterCell(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.FooterCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
{
    e.Info.DisplayText = "Total value for " + gridView1.GetGroupRowValue(e.RowHandle).ToString() + " = " + e.Info.Value;
}

private void gridView1_ShownEditor(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ColumnView view = (ColumnView)sender;
    if (view.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "Number" && view.ActiveEditor is RadioGroup)
    {
        RadioGroup edit = (RadioGroup)view.ActiveEditor;
        //You can add the items at run time.
        edit.Properties.Items.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.RadioGroupItem[] 
        {
            new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.RadioGroupItem(0, "Item 1"),
            new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.RadioGroupItem(1, "Item 2"),
            new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.RadioGroupItem(2, "Item 3")
        });
    }
}
```

Bind the values in the editor control using ShownEditor event of the grid so that it will set the selected item in group..

Hope this help

Comment: Unfortunately, I did the same representing in the example in  the link  "Radio Group as Repository Item not working for multiple rows" but I still have the same pbm.